# Excluding certain nodes from being used in cypher's allShortestPaths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am looking for a method to exclude nodes that have a relationship with another node when using `allShortestPaths()`

This is basically a copy of https://community.neo4j.com/t5/neo4j-graph-platform/excluding-certain-paths-from-allshortestpaths/td-p/55079

but the answers weren't as useful for me.

The first suggestion with GDS and graph projection doesn't let me find all the shortest paths (closest being Yen’s algorithm, but I don't know what k would be to be sure that I get all of the shortest paths)

The second suggestion with `apoc.path.expandConfig()` has the issue where I don't know what the maxLevel would be and leaving it unbounded would take too long to complete the query.

Some other things that I considered but I couldn't get to work include:
1: Using the vanilla `allShortestPaths()` with a GDS graph projection
2: Using `where` and `all()` to ensure that all the nodes in the path follow a rule

This is my attempt for 2:

```
MATCH (whitelist:Category)
WHERE whitelist.label IN $whitelist

MATCH paths = allShortestPaths((source:Material)-[:used_in*]->(dest:Material))
WHERE 
    source.label = $source
    AND dest.label = $dest
    AND all(material IN nodes(paths) WHERE 
        (material)-[:categorised_by]-(whitelist)
        OR NOT (material)-[:categorised_by]-() //or doesn't belong to any category
    )
```

I want to remove all paths who have nodes that are not linked to a node in the whitelist

Some example data:

```
CREATE (msource:Material{label:"source"})
CREATE (m1:Material)
CREATE (m2:Material)
CREATE (m3:Material)
CREATE (m4:Material)
CREATE (m41:Material)
CREATE (mdest:Material{label:"dest"})

CREATE (msource)-[:used_in]->(m1)
CREATE (msource)-[:used_in]->(m2)
CREATE (msource)-[:used_in]->(m3)
CREATE (msource)-[:used_in]->(m4)
CREATE (m4)-[:used_in]->(m41)
CREATE (m1)-[:used_in]->(mdest)
CREATE (m2)-[:used_in]->(mdest)
CREATE (m3)-[:used_in]->(mdest)
CREATE (m41)-[:used_in]->(mdest)

CREATE (cat1:Category{label:"cat1"})
CREATE (cat2:Category{label:"cat2"})

CREATE (m1)-[:categorised_by]->(cat1)
CREATE (m2)-[:categorised_by]->(cat1)
CREATE (m3)-[:categorised_by]->(cat2)
CREATE (m4)-[:categorised_by]->(cat1)
CREATE (m41)-[:categorised_by]->(cat1)
CREATE (mdest)-[:categorised_by]->(cat1)
```

Which results in:
[Visualisation of the example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXj2G.png)

Note how one node is a different category from the others.

And then running my attempt of 2 with

- source = "source"
- dest = "dest"
- whitelist = ["cat1","cat2"]

results in (returning *):

[The shortest paths are returned, but the node with cat2 is not returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gQdz.png)

This is most likely because the query only considers the path to only include one of the whitelisted categories and not a combination.

Comment: An example with a sample graph will be useful. Please give us a view on how your graph looks like. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with attempt nr2?

Comment: @jose_bacoy Thanks, I just updated my question with an example graph.

Comment: @TomažBratanič I updated my question with an example, so I hope this helps. It appears that the whitelist is ignored entirely

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is only a simple typo in your query:

```
 OR NOT (material)-[:categorised]-()
```

Change the relationship type to correct relationship type `categorised_by` and it should work as intended.

```
MATCH (whitelist:Category)
WHERE ID(whitelist) IN $whitelist

MATCH paths = allShortestPaths((source:Material)-[:used_in*]->(dest:Material))
WHERE 
    ID(source) = $source 
    AND ID(dest) = $dest
    AND all(material IN nodes(paths) WHERE 
        (material)-[:categorised_by]-(whitelist)
        OR NOT (material)-[:categorised_by]-() //or doesn't belong to any category
    )
```

> p.s. note that internal node ids are dependent on specific neo4j
> instance and are not a good way to describe your dataset to other
> users. For instance, my internal node ids were between 0 and 7.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo, I converted my real case usage in a hurry and didn't realise that I missed it. Although, my original query doesn't have the typo and the error itself was more difficult to describe in my example data and query usage. I'll amend that now.

Also I realise the id thing, but I was lazy. I'll change that as well.